# Incrementing a php score variable through a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi Guys I was wondering if you could help me with incrementing a score variable inside my code. I am currently programming an online quiz using php and want the score to increment by 1 every time they select the submit button and the specific radio button is checked but when the varible is passed to the results page it comes up as 0

main quiz page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title> World Cup Quiz  </title>
</head>

<script>

function Score()
{
    if(document.getElementById('correct_answer').checked) 
    {
      <?
        $_SESSION['score']=$userScore]+1;
        ?>
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('wrong_answer1').checked) 
    {
      //Wrong 1 radio button is checked
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('wrong_answer2').checked) 
    {
      //Wrong 2 radio button is checked
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('wrong_answer3').checked) 
    {
      //Wrong 3 radio button is checked
    }

}

</script>


<body>
<div align = center><strong> World Cup Quiz</strong></div>
<br />

<div align =center>
<?php



include ("dbConnect.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION['number']))
{
    $_SESSION['number']=1;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['score']))

{
    $_SESSION['score']=0;

}


$questionNumber = $_SESSION['number'];
$userScore=$_SESSION['score'];
$number= rand(1,4);

//search database for generated number and match ID
$dbQuery= "SELECT * FROM `questions 1.0` WHERE  `ID` =$number";
$dbResult=mysql_query($dbQuery);

echo "Question:".$questionNumber."/5<br>";

//Assign variables to each attribute

while ($dbRow=mysql_fetch_array($dbResult))

{
 if ($_SESSION['number']>5)

    {
        header("Location: results.php");
        $_SESSION['number']=1;
        break;


    }

   $theID=$dbRow["ID"];
   $theQuestion=$dbRow["Question"];
   $theAnswer1=$dbRow["Correct Answer"];
   $theAnswer2=$dbRow["Wrong Answer 1"];
   $theAnswer3=$dbRow["Wrong Answer 2"];
   $theAnswer4=$dbRow["Wrong Answer 3"];
   $_SESSION['number']=$questionNumber+1;


}

  //Print Questions and Answers


    echo '<strong>'."$theQuestion".'</strong><br>';
   ?> <form name="correctAnswer" form method="post" action="quiz.php" onSubmit="Score()"> 
  <?php
   echo "$theAnswer1";?> <input type="radio" id="correct_answer" name="correctAnswer">
  <?php
   echo "<br>$theAnswer2"; ?> <input type="radio" id="wrong_answer1" name="wrongAnswer1"> 
   <?php
   echo "<br>$theAnswer3"; ?> <input type="radio" id="wrong_answer2" name="wrongAnswer2"> 
   <?php
   echo "<br>$theAnswer4"; ?> <input type="radio" id="wrong_answer3" name="wrongAnswer3"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="score" value="userScore">
   <br><input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
   </form>


</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the results page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>

</head>

<title> Result</title>

<body>

    <?php

    $score=$_SESSION['score'];

    echo "Congratulations you scored $score /5"

    ?>

    <form action="menu.php">

    <input type="submit" value="Return to Main Menu">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope you can help

Thanks

Comment: $_SESSION['score']=$userScore]+1; should be         $_SESSION['score']=$userScore+1; maybe ?

Comment: You cannot mix JS and PHP like this. The PHP in that function will be executed once (when the page is requested). The JS will execute when specified and do nothing (as it can't "see" the PHP code)

Comment: You need to understand the difference between CLIENT vs. SERVER programming. The UI events happen on the client (JS) and the PHP stuff happens on the server. You can't intermix client and server code and expect them to work in the way you're showing.

Comment: can't believe i missed that but unfortunately that didn't fix it

Comment: do you guys have any ideas how i can achieve this using my current code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a php session variable with client side javascript.
Your javascript has to submit to a server side php file (with ajax) that could return the new value

Answer (score 0):

You can store the score in a cookie which is available to both js and php.

The javascript side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // When starting, set the score to 0.
   setCookie("score", 0, minutesuntilexpires)

   function score(){
    ...
        minutesuntilexpires = 60;
        score = getcookie("score");
        setCookie("score", score + 1, minutesuntilexpires);
    ...
    }

function setCookie(name, value, minutes) {
    minutes = typeof minutes !== 'undefined' ? minutes : 60 ;
    var date= new Date();
    if (minutes < 0){       
        expires = "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    }
    else{
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(minutes*60*1000));
        expires = date.toUTCString();
    }        

    var value = escape(value) + "; expires="+expires;

    document.cookie=name + "=" + value + '; path=/';
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var value = document.cookie;
    var start = value.indexOf(" " + name + "=");
    if (start == -1) {
        start = value.indexOf(name + "=");
    }
    if (start == -1) {
        value = null;
    }
    else {
        start = value.indexOf("=", start) + 1;
        var end = value.indexOf(";", start);
        if (end == -1) {
            end = value.length;
        }
        value = unescape(value.substring(start,end));
    }
    return value;
}

</script>
```

php side:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['score'])){
    $score = $_COOKIE['score'];
}
```